# How to return data response using express?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am trying to run `.get` on a JSON file I've set up located at `/scripts/src/data/*.json` when I make the request I set the headers but I'm not sure how I actually return the resulting data or where I can view this request. Can someone offer any help?

**JS**

```
server.get('/scripts/src/data/*.json', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    // return ??
});
```

Comment: You're looking for `res.send()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use static middleware to serve your json files ,

```
server.use(express.static(__dirname + "/scripts/src/data"))
//other routes
```

In client side , you just should request GET localhost:port/file.json

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
server.get('/scripts/src/data/*.json', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    res.status(200);
    res.json({
        hello: "world"
    });
    // return ??
});
```

Comment: Yeah this returns the `hello:world` object, how do I make this my requested data?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're asking here.  This allows you to send any data back but not the specific file.  :)